# How to GetTimesCalled with exact arguments?

Tags: typemock-isolator

I'm just familiarizing with Typemock Isolator, so sorry, if the question below is stupid.
Can i somehow get times of my function was called with exact arguments?
Like Isolate.Verify.GetTimesCalled() + Isolate.Verify.WasCalledWithExactArguments()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typemock doesn't have a function for getting number of calls with exact arguments. However, you can solve this problem using DoInstead():

```
public class UnderTestClass
{
    public void Foo(int n)
    {
        //Doesn't matter
    }
}

[TestMethod, Isolated]
public void VerifyNumberOfCalls()
{
    //Arrange
    var underTest = new UnderTestClass();

    int number = 0;
    Isolate.WhenCalled((int n) => underTest.Foo(n)).AndArgumentsMatch(n => n <= 0).DoInstead(context =>
    {
        number++;
        context.WillCallOriginal();
    });

    //Act
    underTest.Foo(2);
    underTest.Foo(1);
    underTest.Foo(0);
    underTest.Foo(-1);
    underTest.Foo(-2);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(3, number);
}
```